# TextView in ListView does not trigger onItemClick when it has OnLongClickListener set

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView where row items have some TextViews. One TextView should be long clickable so I put a listener (OnLongClickListner) on it inside custom Adapter. But when I click on this TextView to trigger onclick method for whole list item it does nothing.

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: please post your adapter code

Comment: what does it mean? please explain in detail